Cannot read property 'getClient' of undefined error - spfx Microsoft Graph
I have been trying to use MS Graph in my spfx project but get the following error:
'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getClient')' when running gulp serve.
I am using the following Microsoft template for the project
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph
I have followed the tutorial but have got nowhere trying to find a solution to this.
I am using React with the most recent version of the SharePoint framework installed on a new VM.
I have placed the following in the public render() function as shown in the tutorial:
this.context.msGraphClientFactory
.getClient('3')
.then((client: MSGraphClientV3): void => {
client
.api('/me')
.get((error: any, user: MicrosoftGraph.User, rawResponse?: any) => {
// handle the response
});
Once I comment out the getClient('3'), the project builds successfully and loads with no errors.
Any help greatly appreciated! I've been lost in this for the last 3 days!
